# Web Services over IBM MQ

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, ibm-mq

We have to develop a reliable file transfer mechanism between two systems and I was wondering if we can use IBM MQ with REST web services.

I have found on the web that we can do IBM MQ with SOAP web services but was wondering there would be size limitations as the file sizes can go upto 6GB. With REST tho, we can send large files as unlike SOAP we do not have the header body envelope and all that kind off stuff.

Can you let me know if I am thinking on the right lines ?

Comment: Have you looked at MQ Managed File Transfer?  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/product_overview.htm

Comment: @Shashi I have just taken a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And there is an open source project called Universal File Mover (UFM): http://www.capitalware.biz/ufm_overview.html

Why build a file transfer product when you can use an existing one. UFM can send files of any size to any platform.